# How extract folder php

Tags: php

I'm trying to extact a zip folder in php, I'm using ZipArchive for do that but it doesn't work.

I check the permission and it's ok
I also check the destination and it's ok too

```
 $zip = new \ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($pathShapeFile, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE)) {
   var_dump($zip);
   $path = pathinfo($pathShapeFile);
   $path_tmp = $path['dirname'] . DS . $path['filename'] . '_dezip';
   if(!is_dir($path_tmp)) {
      mkdir($path_tmp);
      chmod($path_tmp, 0777);
   }

   $extract = $zip->extractTo($path_tmp);
}
```

The folder of destination is created by it's empty

$extract return object(ZipArchive)#515 (5) { ["status"]=> int(0) ["statusSys"]=> int(0) ["numFiles"]=> int(0) ["filename"]=> string(50) "/srv/files/shape/Dossier514.zip.zip" ["comment"]=> string(0) "" } and this line "$zip->open($pathShapeFile, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE)" return true

Comment: Why are you using the flags `::CREATE` and `::OVERWRITE` if all you're doing is reading an existing archive? As [the manual shows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.open.php), just do: `->open('the-existing-file.zip')`. The manual also explains what those flags does. For example: _"ZipArchive::OVERWRITE (int) - **If archive exists, ignore its current contents. In other words, handle it the same way as an empty archive.**"_

Comment: If I do $zip->open($pathShapeFile) it return me int(9) so ZipArchive::ER_NOENT but the file is present

Comment: Finally, it was that, I call the extractTo into a fonction with the path in param but there is a '.zip' too much, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code.

you are creating archive rather than opening it.

```
$zip->open($pathShapeFile, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) //this is for archive creation
```

so, replace your code with

```
$pathShapeFile = '/tmp/yourziparchive.zip';
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($pathShapeFile)) { // here you open file, no create and owerwrite mask!
   $path = pathinfo($pathShapeFile);
   $path_tmp = "{$path['dirname'] . DS . $path['filename'] . '_dezip'; //here i don't know what is DS, but let's assume that this is your syntax mistake
   if(!is_dir($path_tmp)) {
      mkdir($path_tmp);
      chmod($path_tmp, 0777); //i don't think you need 777 rights on created dir, but it is your choice
   }

   $extract = $zip->extractTo($path_tmp);
}
$zip->close();
```

i don't know your `$pathShapeFile` value, but it seems that or there is no full path (maybe relative to script but parsed wrong). So as you see in my example you have to use absolute path.